# VS Break point not stopping code execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, breakpoints

Very odd behaviour from this code. I have a function that gets the email addresses to send email to and a second function to send mail. I am putting a break point at the start of the second function to view the list of address and then I stop code execution. Issue is the program still send emails. The SMTP client code is not executing (well it shouldn't be)  I'll comment in code to explain more.

```
//The calling function 
protected void LogRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WriteNewRequest();
   String mysomething = "something";
    SendNewRequestNotification(mysomething , "my subject", "email body");
    ClearForm();

}

private void SendNewRequestNotification(string something, string subject, string message)
{
    List<string> addresslist = new List<string>();
    addresslist.Add(something);
    SendMail(addresslist, subject,message);
}

// I am calling this function
private void SendMail(String address, string subject, string message)
{
    List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
    addresses.Add(address);
    SendMail(addresses,subject,message);
}

private void SendMail(List<String> addresses, string subject, string message)
{
    var toAddress = "";
    toAddress = string.Join(",", addresses.Select(item=>item + "@something.com"));
    //my breakpoint is on the line below. At this point I stop the program. But emails are beign sent. 
    toAddress = "something@something.com"; // this line is just for testing
    var fromAddress = "no.reply@something.com";
    //var subject = "something";
    const string fromPassword = "something";
    string body = message + System.Environment.NewLine + "Date: " + DateTime.Now;
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
       //I put a breakpoint here to test and this never gets a hit but as I said, emails are still being sent. 
        smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 600000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: Is SendMail executing asynchronously perhaps?

Comment: The brackets are pointless. If you wanted to use object initialization you should have written `new SmptClient{ Host="...", Port=25,}` etc

Comment: How would I know?  The application is single threaded. The Calling function calls a few functions in order.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on **every line in the function** do _any_ of them get hit?

Comment: All breakpoint get hit in order. When I press play, it goes to next breakpoint and so. But even if I stop before the line that sends the mail. The email still gets sent.

Comment: Yeah 100%, if I comment out the last line of SendMail, then the email is not sent.

Comment: Ok I think I have worked it out.  When I stop the execution in VS, it doesn't close the browser window, instead the application is usable until I close it. Is normal behaviour for WebForms applications?

Comment: If the app is terminated, whether the browser is open or not **should** be irrelevant.